# problems with mouse hovering on a whole page

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

Since last week I've been creating an HTML site, and I've been using mouse hovering to make image move when your cursor hover on a hyperlink, so everything seems fine and I mostly finished it but there is something that I quite don't understand, I've created 3 hyperlink with 3 mouse hovering images, but the last one actually hovers on the whole page of the site.

I have no idea why or where it does that so that is why I'm here to ask you this question. You can take a look at my html:

```css
.college .image {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college .imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.lycee .image {
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0px, 300px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.formations .image {
  margin-left: 1250px;
  margin-top: 510px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0, -900px);
}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/571x179") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0, 85, 170);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Do you have any ideas that can help me? Or improve my lines of code that I've made so far? Thank you alot!

Comment: Hey souzouker, next time please pay a bit more attention to your writing (capitalization) and use the editor button to turn your code into a Stack Snippet so we can easily reproduce your issue. This will help us help you. By the way, all I see is blue. You should replace the image `src`s with [placeholder images](https://placeholder.com/). I would've done it, but you did not specifiy `width` or `height` for your images (you should).

Comment: i think its all blue because i use files and images from my computer i can try to change it with placeholder images give me a minute please

Comment: i think it worked you can see it on full page how it works , you can see that the 3rd image hovers on the whole page execpt the 2 orther hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `left` and `top` rather than `margin-left` and `margin-top`. The margins of the images are causing the `a` tag to expand in size.

```css
.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college .imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0px, 300px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/571x179") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0, 85, 170);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you're right! i didn't know margin actually do that, thank you so much !

Comment: No problem. Margins are essentially adding additional space around an element, which will add to the size of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

In the last a you hav closed the opening saintemarie div before closing the a tag see here

```
 <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
        <div class="formations">
            <img class="image imagefifth" src="formation.png" />
            <img class="image imagesixth" src="pepepls.gif" />
        </div>
     /* closed before a */   </div>  
    </a>
```

Try closing it after the a and see if it gets all right

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i've fixed it in my codes, 
Unfortunately, it didn't fixed my problem yet, but thanks you ^^

Comment: can you use http images and attach a code snippet so that i can get a better look at it

Answer (score 0):

```css
.college .image {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college .imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.lycee .image {
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0px, 300px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(0, -200px);
}

.formations .image {
  margin-left: 1250px;
  margin-top: 510px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(0, -900px);
}

body {
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/571x179") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0, 85, 170);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```